# iOS - Charts by Daniel Gindi - I got a doubled xAxis in the line chart! Anyone ever came across this issue?

Tags: ios, swift, charts

[Notice the xAxis, and it's a doubled line, which is out of my expectation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkqTH.png)

Btw, I don't want the lines that are parallel with the xAxis. I've tried almost every piece of code but none worked to wipe the parallel lines. Any suggestion will be appreciated >_<

Code is as below. ignore the fragments in the comments

```
    data = lineChartData
    chartDescription?.text = ""
    chartDescription?.textColor = UIColor.white
    noDataText = "No Data"
    noDataTextColor = UIColor.white

    // xAxis
    xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: dataPoints)
    xAxis.granularity = 1.0
    xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.white
    xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false

    // legend
    legend.textColor = UIColor.orange
    legend.verticalAlignment = .top
    legend.horizontalAlignment = .left


    rightAxis.enabled = false

    // touch
    scaleXEnabled = false
    scaleYEnabled = false
    dragEnabled = true

    lineChartDataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = false
    lineChartDataSet.colors = [UIColor.orange]
    lineChartDataSet.valueColors = [UIColor.white]
```

When I commented all the code about chart appearance, I got this:
[commented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaVrZ.png)
The ends of the yAxis stretched down. Is it a bug of the library? Or if I missed something...

Comment: Please include the code in your question, not an external link.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't. To post an image, my reputation needs to be more than 10. You know, I'm a newbie [embarassed]

Comment: @user33239 Raptor suggested you to post **code** which you can do with any amount of rep. Not an image/link

Comment: @user33239 you are having an usual issue and without us knowing what code you have to produce your current output we cannot help you.

Comment: Edit your question. Putting codes in comments are too hard to read.